# Xcode Interface Builder wont start

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I have a relatively confusing problem: I created several empty Xcode projects and ran the iPhone and iPad emulators just to see what happens and everything is fine, empty, but fine. However, then I decided to actually add some content but when I double click my .xib file nothing happens. The Xcode loses focus, but nothing opens. The Interface Builder simply does not open.

Do I need to start it separately somehow or do I need to download and install it separately or something else altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common cause of this in my experience is failure to reboot after installing or upgrading Xcode. Xcode gives you the impression that you don't need a reboot, but in practice you do. Have you done this yet?

Comment: Yes. I have installed Xcode two days ago and I did a complete shutdown. I started it up yesterday and that's when I wanted to play with it :(

BUT! When I installed it, I DID start it and I DID create a few projects and ran them to see the emulator. This I did before the shutdown. Could this be somehow significant?

Comment: It's very unlikely that running things too soon caused the problem. The usual problem is that LaunchServices doesn't get updated. Does IB bounce in the dock when you double-click a XIB? What happens if you double-click the XIB in Finder and double-click IB in /Developer/Applications?

Comment: I will have to try that tonight (still at work). When I double clicked it in Xcode nothing happened, no bouncing, nothing, only Xcode lost focus. Stupid Q: How do i find /Developer/Applications?

Comment: In Finder, type Cmd-Shift-G and type in /Developer. Or you can go to the top of your hard-drive and you'll find it there.

Comment: THANKS!!! The problem was that the .xib files were not "registered"... when i tried to open it from Finder it said "i don't have a standard program for this" (loose translation from german)... then I went into Developer/Applications and started IB which worked. Then I did a right-click and Open With... on the .xib file and selected IB and since then it works from Xcode as well!
THANKS A BUNCH Rob!!!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem when i first installed xcode.

What solved it for me was manually starting the Interface Builder once (via spotlight).

After that it worked again by double clicking on the xib file in xcode....

Comment: this worked for me as well...however, I have had to open it manually every time after a restart.

Answer (score 0):

Try to search for interface builder in Mac OS search bar on the top right of the screen, open it, click on open existing file. Open any xib file once, then it will be automatically detectedd by xCode.